# Listing Parameters of an Object in an ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, tostring

I am trying to create a method to list the elements in an ArrayList, but the method only returns the values of the most recent object:

The object:

```
//Constructor for guests at the hotel
public Guest (String name, String checkinDate, String checkoutDate, double depAmt)
{
    gstName = name;
    checkIn = checkinDate;
    checkOut = checkoutDate;
    deposit = depAmt;
}
```

Current objects in the ArrayList:

```
//Fills the roster with three guests to start the program
public static void fillGuest()
{
    Guest guest1 = new Guest("Mike P.", "2/13/16", "2/23/16", 360.00);
    guestList.add(guest1);
    Guest guest2 = new Guest("Randall M.", "4/10/16", "4/17/16", 120.00);
    guestList.add(guest2);
    Guest guest3 = new Guest("Bo-Diddly.", "4/20/16", "4/23/16", 600.00);
    guestList.add(guest3);
}
```

Method to list the objects in the ArrayList:

```
public static void returnGuests()
{
    System.out.println("Currently checked in "  + guestList.size() + " guests:");
    for (int i = 0; i <= guestList.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(guestList.get(i));
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Currently checked in 3 guests:
Bo-Diddly. 4/20/16 4/23/16 600.0
Bo-Diddly. 4/20/16 4/23/16 600.0
Bo-Diddly. 4/20/16 4/23/16 600.0

Enter command:
```

How do I display the individual object parameters of each Guest object?

Comment: are you sure you haven't defined your fields as static? Show us the full Guest code source

Comment: Have you looked into using a `foreach` loop at all?  This would be in place of your existing `for` loop.

Comment: This is a very strong indication your `Guest` class is written incorrectly.

Comment: show the declaration of 'gstName',   'checkIn' ,   'checkOut',   'deposit' fields in the 'Guest.java'

Answer (score 0):

Your `Guest` object should look like below. Note the lack of the `static` modifier on the fields. Also, note the use of the `this` keyword. If you use that with a `static` variable, then your IDE should give you a warning that it will be interpreted as a `MyClass.var` instead of `this.var`.

Your problem is that all `Guest` objects will have the last set of variables as you create new `Guest` objects. You need to use "instance" variables instead of "class" variables.

If you would like to read more on the topic of static "class" variables, please see [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

```
public class Guest {

    String gstName, checkIn, checkOut;
    double deposit;

    public Guest (String name, String checkinDate, String checkoutDate, double depAmt)
    {
        this.gstName = name;
        this.checkIn = checkinDate;
        this.checkOut = checkoutDate;
        this.deposit = depAmt;
    }
}
```